# Indirect Only filter for Collections not supported in EEVEE?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, collections

does anyone know if the indirect only button is unsupported in EEVEE? It works perfect in Cycles to bypass rendering a collection except for reflections, but in EEVEE it appears to do nothing.

Thanks!

-Adam

[image: indirect-only-not-working-in-blender-eevee]

Cycles with "indirect only" on collection:

[image: cycles-indirect-only]

EEVEE with "indirect only" on collection:

[image: eevee-indirect-only]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is a [feature that works only in Cycles](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/outliner.html#restriction-columns).

> **Indirect Only (collection only)**
>
> Objects in these collections only contribute to indirect light – *Cycles only*.

Comment: Great, thank you for confirming that, RJG! That explains it. Hopefully that feature will come to EEVEE soon... :-)